# Why this regex does split second double quote but not first double quote?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex:

```
let regex = /(?=\.|[\"])/;
test = "\"test.test\""
test.split(regex)
```

which outputs:

```
[""test", ".test", """]
```

whereas I want

```
[""", "test", ".test", """]
```

I can't see why it splits second double quote but not first double quote

P.S.: must keep ".test" like that (and not "." "test")

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks will study that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not pure regex solution but you may use this regex with a capture group and filter empty results:

```js
const str = '"test.test"';

var arr = str.split(/(")|(?=\.)/).filter(Boolean)

console.log(arr)
```

---

**Issue with your approach:**

Your regex is using a lookahead assertion that can be shortened to:

```
(?=[."])
```

Which means match a zero width match that has either a dot or `"` at immediate next position.

Since your input has `"` at the start it matches position 0, then position before dot and finally position before last closing `"`  (total 3 matches).

Comment: I do want actually dot attached: ".test"