# How to specify in regex to split : except within 2 double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

Subsequent to [Why this regex does split second double quote but not first double quote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61370069/why-this-regex-does-split-second-double-quote-but-not-first-double-quote)

I now added :, problem is I don't want to split if it is inside double quotes:

```
let regex = /(?=\.|[\":])/;
test = "test: \"test.test:\""
test.split(regex)
```

gives

```
["test", ": ", ""test", ".test", ":", """]
```

whereas I would like to have

```
["test", ": ", ""test", ".test:", """]
```

is it possible for regex (I'm not good at all at it)?

Comment: You added the `:` without actually using the suggested solution? Again, note there is no sense separating `\.` and `[":]` patterns since both matcha single char, `(?=\.|[\":])` is the same as `(?=[.":])`. Actually, your desired result is equal to the current output.

Comment: Current output and expected outputs are exactly same.

Comment: @anubhava because I made a bad copy and paste just fixed ;)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I made a bad copy and paste. I used previous solution from anubhava because it was simpler to start with. I have yet to understand the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex to match `:` only outside quotes (assuming quotes are all balanced and unescaped):

```js
const test = "test: \"test.test:\""
var arr = test.split(/(?=[."])|:(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)/)

console.log( arr )
```

Here, `(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)` is a lookahead that asserts that we have even number of quotes ahead of current position.